# IOS application freezes after link share

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new to ios development. I am doing my first project and I want to implement a small application that will allow saving favorite links from the browser. I am using SwiftUI for main app + share extension component to pass link to main app from browser.
The flow looks like this: I find an interesting site, click the Share button and select the icon for my application. After that, my application opens and there I see my link. This works successfully, but after that the browser freezes completely. If I post a link from other apps, the same thing happens.

Below is the code of the share extension and the component of the main application that reads the link:

```
@objc(ShareExtensionViewController)
class ShareViewController: UIViewController {

    private static let URL_STORAGE_KEY = "url"
    private static let APP_URL = "MyApp://"
    private static let APP_GROUP_NAME = "group.ru.myapp"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // set link to UserDefaults
        handleShared()
        // open main app from extension
        openMainApp()
    }

    @objc
    @discardableResult
    func openURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool {
        var responder: UIResponder? = self
        while responder != nil {
            if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
                return application.perform(#selector(openURL(_:)), with: url) != nil
            }
            responder = responder?.next
        }
        return false
    }

    private func openMainApp() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: nil, completionHandler: { _ in
                let url = URL(string: ShareViewController.APP_URL)!
                self.openURL(url)
            })
        }
    }

    private func handleShared() {
        let attachments = (extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem)?.attachments ?? []
        let contentType = kUTTypeURL as String
        for provider in attachments {
            if provider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentType) {
                provider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentType, options: nil) {
                    [unowned self] (data, error) in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        return
                    }
                    let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: ShareViewController.APP_GROUP_NAME)!
                    userDefaults.set(data, forKey: ShareViewController.URL_STORAGE_KEY)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Snippet of the main application code:

```
static func tryGetLink() -> String? {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: DataStorage.APP_GROUP)
    return userDefaults?.object(forKey: URL_KEY) as? String
}
```

What could be the reason for these freezes?

Comment: Impossible to say from posted code. Either you are blocking the main thread somehow, or exhausting memory - these are most typical reasons for freeze. You have to debug/profile it.

Comment: @KirilS. Thanks for the answer. It is strange, but when debugging this problem is not reproducible. This only happens if I run a release build and, interestingly, it only happens in ~ 70% of attempts

Comment: Such random reproducibility is typical to threading issues. So I would be even more suspicious about threading issues in your app (run thread sanitizer for example, and not on simulator, but on a fairly busy real device)